# Is there a way to detect multiple key inputs at once in processing?

Tags: keyboard, processing

I am using processing.py and I am using keyPressed and key to detect keyboard input in my program. However, this means that only the most recently pressed key will be detected. For example, if I hold down g, and press h while holding down g, the program will only detect the h. How do I detect whether or not g is still being pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use the [`keyPressed`](https://py.processing.org/reference/keyPressed_var.html) and [`key`](https://py.processing.org/reference/key.html) variables, you'll only be able to get the most recent key.

But you can get this to work by using the [`keyPressed()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/keyPressed.html) and [`keyReleased()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/keyReleased.html) functions together to keep track of which keys are currently down (keyPressed has fired for the key, but keyReleased has not).

Here's a simple example:

```
gIsDown = False

def draw():
    if gIsDown:
        background(255)
    else :
        background(0)


def keyPressed():
    global gIsDown
    if key == 'g':
        gIsDown = True

def keyReleased():
    global gIsDown
    if key == 'g':
        gIsDown = False
```

If you need to keep track of more than one or two keys then you probably want to store the down states in an array so you don't have to create a bunch of individual variables for all the key states. You can use the [`keyCode`](https://py.processing.org/reference/keyCode.html) as array indexes to make this easier.